# Joint probability based on assuming linear relationships

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution, independence

I am a statistical novice trying to work something out which is probably basic. Or impossible. I have discrete probability distributions for two random discrete variables $A$ and $B$.

I want to find probabilities like $P(A=k \cap B=j)$. When $A$ and $B$ are independent, I can just multiply $P(A=k)$ and $P(B=j)$. But in my setting I want to try to model situations where $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

As a very simple case, I'd like to assume that maybe there is some linear relationship between A and B, so that, say, if A ends up observed higher than expected, then B will probably also end up higher than expected. This linear relationship would have a constant built in, say $C_{A,B}$. I'm imagining $C_{A,B}=1$ would mean they are directly correlated, 0 means they are independent, and -1 means inversely correlated.

I assume this kind of thing is well-known- what is the appropriate language and framework for me to be using? Ideally I'd like a formula for computing $P(A=k \cap B=j)$ in terms of $C$ and $P(A=k)$ and $P(B=j)$.

(This is a duplicate of a post at math.stackexchange, which got no answers- sorry if that's frowned upon)

Comment: Isn't this an application of the definition of conditional probability? i.e., $P(A=k \cap B=j) = P(A = k \mid B = j) \cdot P(A =k)$. To proceed, you would have to find some way to compute $P(A = k \mid B = j)$ (e.g., estimate it from data), but that's all there is.

Comment: @chang_trenton Yes I suppose equivalently I'm asking how to generate the conditional probabilities $P(A=k \mid B=j)$. I feel like there should be some kind of simple "linear correlation" model in which you assume $A$ and $B$ have some kind of linear relationship, and then this tells you what $P(A=k \mid B=j)$ ought to be.

Comment: You could look into **copulas**, see the tag [tag:copula]. Maybe add that tag!